# If Else Query with Parameters

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I got an error 2x:

> A local or parameter named 'q' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

What am I doing wrong here? I have a dropdownlist in my view then I pass the value to the @dropdowncategory parameter

This is my code:

```
cmd.Connection = con;
string dropdownsearch = "@dropdowncategory";
string q;
if (dropdownsearch == "ID")
{
    string q = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = @id";
}
else
{
    string q = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name = @name";
}

cmd.Parameters.AddRange(queryParams.ToArray());
cmd.CommandText = q;
con.Open();
```

Comment: Declare `string q` before `if`

Comment: [Scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) FTW!

Comment: I've updated my code, got another error

Comment: To me, this is not a question for Stack Overflow but something you should find in _every_ basic programming book.

Comment: Your new error is because you declare new variables with the same name in the `if` and `else`, just remove the `string` before `q` in both cases.

Comment: Both answers show the solution to your new error as well. Being precise is important. You are now defining `q` **three** times when you need it only once!

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing wrong is that your are defining `q` in the [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) (*) of your `if` and your `else` branch only. That means it does not exist outside it.

This should work:

```
string q;
if (dropdownsearch == "ID")
{
    q = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = @id";
}
else
{
    q = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name = @name";
}

cmd.Parameters.AddRange(queryParams.ToArray());
cmd.CommandText = q;
con.Open();
```

Alternatively, you can do something like:

```
string q = dropdownsearch == "ID"
    ? "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = @id"
    : "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name = @name";
cmd.CommandText = q;
```

Or go all the way to be concise, and get rid of `q` alltogether:

```
cmd.CommandText = dropdownsearch == "ID"
    ? "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = @id"
    : "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name = @name";
```

(*) Thank you @Uwe Keim for proposing the link!

Comment: Seems the OP is not aware of the concept of [scopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)). Better put a link to explain.

Comment: I'm using your alternative code, still not working, no errors but only the 2nd statements is working, the WHERE name = @name

Comment: @Hansmagz Then you rcmdtext is never equal to "ID". Maybe it is "Id" or "id"? Debugging might help!

Answer (score 1):

The scope of `q` is within the brackets (`if` / `else`). Declare it outside and your code will compile.

```
cmd.Connection = con;
string dropdownsearch = "@dropdowncategory";
string q;
if (dropdownsearch == "ID")
{
    q = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = @id";
}
else
{
    q = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name = @name";
}

cmd.Parameters.AddRange(queryParams.ToArray());
cmd.CommandText = q;
con.Open();
```

Comment: Seems the OP is not aware of the concept of [scopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)).